# load csv file in sql table using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a task to read csv file and load the csv file to sql table but I am not sure of my code and facing "No suitable driver error" and tried with new driver.

```
val DBURL= "jdbc:sqlserver://servername:port;DatabaseName=DBname"  
val srcfile=spark.read.text("filename")
val test =srcfile.write.format("jdbc")
          .option("url", DBURL)
          .option("dbtable", "tablename")
          .option("user", "username")
          .option("password", "password")
          .save()
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: have you include the dependency in built manager like maven or sbt ?

Comment: we are not using maven and sbt. simply we have to read file from hdfs and insert it in to sql table

Comment: did you download the jdbc connector?

Comment: yes this one is may latest jar"mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar" using this I am able to connect table but not  able to load csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the corresponding driver also in the option, like 
.option ("driver","org.postgresql.Driver")
or
.option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

Comment: Please refer this previous post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552799/spark-unable-to-find-jdbc-driver

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following answer will help you and it is tried one so it must not have any kind of error

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Testing Transpose").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true")
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
 val sparksession = SparkSession.builder().config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","file:///c://tmp/spark-warehouse").getOrCreate()

 val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
 import sqlContext.implicits._

 val df = sparksession.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load(Path)

 val prop : java.util.Properties = new Properties()
 prop.setProperty("user","(temp_User)")
 prop.setProperty("password","(temp_password)")

 df
  .write
  .option("driver","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
  .mode("append")
  .jdbc("jdbc:sqlserver://(database_ip):(database_port_to_access)","(table_name)",prop)

sparksession.stop()
}
```

include this dependency if you want to use databricks.csv else you can replace it
`val df = sparkSession.read.option("header","true").csv("src/main/resources/sales.csv")`

this needed to be included in *build.sbt*
`libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "0.1"`

if your file doesn't have header then you can provide them header like the following

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
    df.toDF("column_name_1","column_name_2",.....)
```

**Note**: The number of column names must be similar to the number of columns in the dataframe and one more thing to note you need to change the header option to false like follows

`sparksession.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").load(Path)`

Comment: but my data file does'nt have header. without header showing errors like invalid column name

Comment: i have added some notes/comments at the end of the answer please go through that and you will be probably able to solve your problem. feel free to ping if required

Comment: please inform whether it helper you out or not