# No suitable driver found for jdbc:amazonaws

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-athena

I'm trying to connect to amazon athena using JDBC. As I didn't find the *AthenaDriver* repository on maven, I created it myself on my [github](https://github.com/raphael-psr/maven-repository). Basically what I'm doing is this:

pom.xml:

```
<repository>
    <id>mvn-rep</id>
    <name>maven repository</name>
    <url>https://github.com/raphael-psr/maven-repository/raw/master/</url>
</repository>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>AthenaJDBC41</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

java:

```
class.forName("com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver");

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("user", user);
properties.setProperty("password", password);
properties.setProperty("aws_credentials_provider_class", "amazon.AmazonCredentialsProvider");

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:awsathena://athena." + region + ".amazonaws.com:443", properties);
```

An exception is raised:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:amazonaws://athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443

Anyone knows what it might be?

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe you would like to download the JDBC driver from: https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar
2. You can install it on your own maven repository:

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/users/User01/Documents/AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc -DartifactId=athenaJDBC -Dpackaging=jar
   ```
3. Then you can reference it in your pom.xml:

[image]

Let me know if that helps you somehow.

PS: Not sure why code formatting is not working in my computer. I've tried three different browsers and I'm expecting the same issue.

Comment: Code formatting in a list requires and indentation of 8, not 4 (4 to make the block a paragraph of the list and another 4 to make it code).

Comment: That's exactly what I did when I created the [repository](https://github.com/raphael-psr/maven-repository) and the `class.forName("com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver")` does't return any exception.

Answer (score 1):

Download Jar from https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar

Add the jar to your own maven repository

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/sumit/Downloads/AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc -DartifactId=athenaJDBC -Dversion=1.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

change **-Dfile** value to your downloaded jar path.
If required update **-Dversion**.

Add dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>athenaJDBC</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across this problem myself using the `2.0.2` of the `JDBC42` version of the driver while developing a Spark job in Clojure. Despite those difference I think the answer will translate and I got it from [Spark Unable to find JDBC Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552799/spark-unable-to-find-jdbc-driver).

I believe you need to set the `driver` property in your `Properties` object to the Athena Driver class i.e.

```
properties.setProperty("driver", "com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver");
```

which is correct for the `2.0.2` version. In you case is should be

```
properties.setProperty("driver", "com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver");
```

I don't know why the `Class.forName` isn't sufficient. I also had to build my own Maven package to include.