# I am attempting to access a mysql table from pyspark. I am attempting this using :

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

```
esp_domains = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://my.ip.com/tablename") \
  .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "tablename")\
  .option("user", "root").option("password", "root") \
  .load()
```

This hits some error that spews a lot of text, containing:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o49.load.: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Drive
```

I've put a file that I apparently need , namely

mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar

in various places including

```
/usr/share/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar
/usr/bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar
```

although I don't find a openjdk 10.0.1 folder to put this in.

Comment: you are using spark and so driver must be in the library of spark not java.

Comment: pass the jar as `--driver-class-path /usr/share/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar` to your `spark-submit` command

Comment: [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552799/spark-unable-to-find-jdbc-driver/46278476) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function. Pass it a SparkSession object and other relevant variables. The SQL driver gets downloaded automatically, as far as I know.

```
def connect_to_sql(spark, jdbc_hostname, jdbc_port, database, data_table, username, password):
    jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbc_hostname, jdbc_port, database)

    connection_details = {
        "user": username,
        "password": password,
        "driver": "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    }

    df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=data_table, properties=connection_details)
    return df
```